# How to use multiple file patterns in Azure DevOps nuget restore task?

Tags: azure-devops

My conditions are:

- Azure DevOps Server 2022 (not Azure DevOps Services in the Cloud)
- Classic pipelines (not YAML)
- Default NuGet restore task
- I want to include some solutions AND exclude some others

I found this documentation for file matching patterns: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/file-matching-patterns?view=azure-devops

I tried these patterns and they don't restore anything:

- folder/include*.sln;folder/exclude*.sln
- (folder/include*.sln|folder/exclude*.sln)
- [folder/include*.sln|folder/exclude*.sln]

These restore all my solutions:

- **/*.sln
- folder/*.sln

In other words: I am unable to combine two expression inside the nuget restore task.
Documentation suggests to use two lines for two expressions. I cannot do this in the task:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that you have two possibilities

1. Use wild card syntax such as `**\*.sln` taking all solution files from all folders.
2. Combine multiple files with `;` like `myfile1.sln;path\myfile2.sln`

I wanted a combination of both e.g. `includedFolder\*.sln;extraFolder\onlythis.sln` which only works if you don't use any wild card. I used a very long list of valid solutions `includedFolder\include1.sln;includedFolder\include2.sln;includedFolder\include3.sln;extraFolder\myfileX.sln`, because **1. and 2. cannot be used together** (or at least I did not figure out how).